# how to represent oracle blob in play model

Tags: java, oracle, playframework-2.2

I need to load a BLOB column (field name: FOTO) from Oracle to Java Play Framework. I tried using java.sql.Blob in my model (model name: ESTUDIANTE) but i'm getting this error.

```
[error] c.a.e.s.t.r.ImmutableMetaFactory - Was unable to use reflection to find a constructor and appropriate getters forimmutable type interface java
.sql.Blob.  The errors while looking for the getter methods follow:
[error] c.a.e.s.d.p.DeployCreateProperties - Error with models.Estudiante field:foto
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to use reflection to build ImmutableMeta for interface java.sql.Blob.  Associated Errors trying to find a construct
or and getter methods have been logged
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.type.reflect.ImmutableMetaFactory.createImmutableMeta(ImmutableMetaFactory.java:53) ~[avaje-ebeanorm.jar:na]

        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.type.DefaultTypeManager.recursiveCreateScalarTypes(DefaultTypeManager.java:205) ~[avaje-ebeanorm.jar:na]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.DeployCreateProperties.createProp(DeployCreateProperties.java:321) [avaje-ebeanorm.jar:na]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.DeployCreateProperties.createProp(DeployCreateProperties.java:341) [avaje-ebeanorm.jar:na]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.DeployCreateProperties.createProperties(DeployCreateProperties.java:128) [avaje-ebeanorm.jar:na
]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.DeployCreateProperties.createProperties(DeployCreateProperties.java:54) [avaje-ebeanorm.jar:na]
```

Am i doing something wrong? Is there another java datatype to handle blob?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use javax.persistence.Lob;

```
@Lob
//Use basic annotation only if you need to LAZY load. 
@Basic(fetch = LAZY)
public byte[] data;
```

By default @Basic(fetch=EAGER) is provided on java primitives, so annotating @Basic is optional in this case [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Basic.html#fetch()).

Comment: Thanks for reply, i'm not getting the error anymore, but `foto` field is always getting null value, i check the database fields aren't empty, what this could be?

Comment: did you use fetch=LAZY ? if you want to fetch EAGER, try as fetch=EAGER